# Excel VBA OLEDB SQL Query

Tags: sql, excel, vba

ers,

Having trouble using an OLED database connection for creating a SQL query. It's a rather long string of text and I get a too many line continuation error.

```
Sub Query()

Dim Comtext As String

Comtext = "SELECT[Reporting_OMS].[dbo].[Norderparcels].ParcelNumber, 
[Reporting_OMS].[dbo].[Stocktransactions].TransactionNumber, 
[Reporting_OMS].[dbo].[Stocktransactions].TransactionDate, [Reporting_OMS].
[dbo].[Stocktransactions].Tonnage, [Reporting_OMS].[dbo].
[Norderparcels].OwnerWarehouserNumber, [Reporting_OMS].[dbo].[Site].Code, 
[Reporting_OMS].[dbo].[Qcommodities].Code, [Reporting_OMS].[dbo].
[Qgrades].Code, [Reporting_OMS].[dbo].[Businesscontacts].ShortName, 
[Reporting_OMS].[dbo].[Norderparcels].StartDateTime"
Comtext = Comtext & "FROM [Reporting_OMS].[dbo].
[Transferofownershiptransactions], [Reporting_OMS].[dbo].[Norderparcels], 
[Reporting_OMS].[dbo].[Stocktransactions], [Reporting_OMS].[dbo].[Site], 
[Reporting_OMS].[dbo].[Qcommodities], [Reporting_OMS].[dbo].[Qgrades], 
[Reporting_OMS].[dbo].[Businesscontacts]  WHERE 
(Stocktransactions.Id=Transferofownershiptransactions.Stocktransactionid AND 
[Reporting_OMS].[dbo].[Norderparcels].Id=[Reporting_OMS].[dbo].
[Transferofownershiptransactions].Orderparcelid AND [Reporting_OMS].[dbo].
[Site]"
Comtext = Comtext & ".Id=[Reporting_OMS].[dbo].[Norderparcels].Siteid  AND 
[Reporting_OMS].[dbo].[Qgrades].Id=[Reporting_OMS].[dbo].
[Norderparcels].Bingradeid AND [Reporting_OMS].[dbo].
[Norderparcels].Commodityid=[Reporting_OMS].[dbo].[Qcommodities].Id AND 
Businesscontacts.Id=[Reporting_OMS].[dbo].[Norderparcels].Ownertoid)  AND 
(([Reporting_OMS].[dbo].[Businesscontacts].Shortname='CENTRE' AND 
[Reporting_OMS].[dbo].[Norderparcels].Startdatetime BETWEEN {ts '2017-03-01 
00:00:00.000'} AND {ts '2017-04-30 00:00:00.000'} AND [Reporting_OMS].[dbo].
[Norderparcels].Parcelfulfilled='N'))"

Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("adl-sql-011-p_reporting Reporting_OMS").OLEDBConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .CommandText = Array(Comtext)

    .CommandType = xlCmdSql

    .Connection = Array( _
    "OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=Reporting_OMS;Data Source=adl-sql-011-p\" _
    , _
    "reporting;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=ADL-XD-P7-054;Use Encryption for Data=" _
    , "False;Tag with column collation when possible=False")
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .SavePassword = False
    .SourceConnectionFile = ""
    .SourceDataFile = ""
    .ServerCredentialsMethod = xlCredentialsMethodIntegrated
    .AlwaysUseConnectionFile = False

End With
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("adl-sql-011-p_reporting Reporting_OMS")
    .Name = "adl-sql-011-p_reporting Reporting_OMS"
End With



End Sub
```

I know the Query/SQL is fine as it works as a once off it entering it through a new connection.

I also understand that doing the comtext = comtext & ... is super inefficient, but is there a better way?

Cheers!

Comment: You want to add a space after the "select" statement, or you'll get "[Norderparcels].StartDateTimeFROM"

Comment: VBA is happy with really long strings but not with line continuations so just break it down into a few strings and combine them at the end: str1= this text, str2 = this text str3 = str1 & " " & str2